# NaN problem in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, nan

I am converting four bytes to float and I'm getting `NaN` as a result, but I want the value `0.0`. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
public class abc 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] arry = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
        int num = ((arry[0] << 24) & 0xFF000000) | ((arry[1] << 16) & 0xFF0000)
            | ((arry[2] << 8) & 0xFF00) | (arry[3] & 0xFF);
        float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(num);

        f= (float) ((f < 0 ? Math.ceil(f * 10) : Math.floor(f * 10)) / 10);

        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Answer (score 6):

Your main problem is that `0xFFFFFFFF` is indeed a NaN.

A float with a value of 0 is... 0.

Changing the array to

```
int[] arry = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Will change the resulting value to a `0.0f` float.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your bit pattern happens to actually *be* NaN:

> [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) NaNs are represented with the exponential field filled with ones and some non-zero number in the significand. A bit-wise example of a [IEEE floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard) standard single precision NaN: x111 1111 1axx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx where x means [don't care](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t-care). If a = 1, it is a quiet NaN, otherwise it is a signalling NaN.

Since *all* your bits are 1, it obviously fits above criteria and is a *quiet NaN* (although Java iirc doesn't even support quiet or signalling NaNs).

Answer (score 0):

NaN = Not a Number, iaw, the bit pattern 0xFFFFFFFF does not represent a <strike>float value</strike> number. (Joachim, you're right .. again :-) )

Comment: `NaN` is a float value, otherwise you couldn't store it in a `float` variable. It's just not a number ;-)

Comment: Which value do you expect, what is 'correct'? if you want '0.0f', then use {0,0,0,0} int array. If you want the corresponding float for 0xffffffff, then just cast (`float f = (float) num`)